# Using Django DB connection in custom threaded scripts

Tags: python, django, multithreading

There are many questions about is django db connection thread safe, but they all seem to be asking the default request threads.

What if I am writing custom script that uses database connection in threads:

```
from django.db import connections
import threading

class Transform(object):
    def transform_data(self, listing):
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT ... WHERE id = %s', listing.id)
        data  = cursor.fetchall()
        ...

    def run(self):
        connection = self.connections['legacy']
        for listing in listings:
            threading.Thread(target=self.transform_data, args=[listing])
```

How safe is data inside `transform_data` thread in terms of the result from cursor is not mixed up with other threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item in the `connections` object returns a thread-local connection to that database. By default, these connections cannot be shared between threads; attempting to do so will result in a `DatabaseError`.

Always use `connections[alias]` *within* the thread that executes your queries. Never access `connections[alias]` in the parent thread and pass the object to the child thread. This will ensure that every connection object you use is local to the current thread, avoiding any threading issues.

To fix your code and make it thread-safe, you would change it like this:

```
from django.db import connections
import threading

class Transform(object):
    def transform_data(self, listing):
        # Access the database connection on the global `connections` object
        # from within the child thread.
        cursor = connections['legacy'].cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT ... WHERE id = %s', listing.id)
        data  = cursor.fetchall()
        ...

    def run(self):
        for listing in listings:
            threading.Thread(target=self.transform_data, args=[listing])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally each thread should be using its own connection. If you do that when you execute the select query inside transform_data you are essentially getting a snapshot of the data at that point in time. You can retrieve the rows without having to worry about their being updated or deleted by other threads provided that the other threads have their own connection.

If all threads share the same connection what exactly happens is very dependent on what database you are using and transaction isolation level